# MVC 2 - Data Annotation for Label?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model

Is there an annotation to set the Label-name of the property?

Ex:

```
public class MyModel
{

[LabelName("Your Phone")]
public string Phone{get;set;}
}
```

Thanks

And then in the view, it would show the name "Your Phone"

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(Model.Phone)%>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `[DisplayName("Your Phone")]` instead of `[LabelName("Your Phone")]`

Comment: For me (MVC 5) only `[Display(Name="Something nice")]` works as given below. And `[DisplayName` does not compile. I figure Intellisense will guide most readers in the right direction, but still think the accepted answer should be changed to the answer below. So -1 from me :).

Answer (score 17):

If you mean the actual content of the label to be displayed on the page, yes.  It is

```
[Display (Name= "Your Display content")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers I see, while this is an old post, here is the scoop:
(I'm using MVC 5)

**DisplayName** – Defines the text we want used on form fields and validation messages

However I would say to stick with the better and more flexible --> **Display(Name =**

You CAN use either of these

```
[Display(Name = "Add Comments")]
```

which is using this namespace:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

**OR**

```
[DisplayName("Add Comments")]
```

which is using this namespace:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```